# How to put redshift query in function?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

It is very hard to me to remember query for listing all tables in redshift:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tablename
FROM pg_table_def
WHERE schemaname = 'public'
ORDER BY tablename;
```

So I decided to create function that does it to me. But it turns out redshift does not understand "RETURNS TABLE" statement:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TABLE"
LINE 2: RETURNS TABLE (tablename varchar)
            ^
```

I tried with other return types

```
CREATE FUNCTION show_tables()
RETURNS ANYELEMENT VOLATILE
AS 'SELECT DISTINCT tablename
    FROM pg_table_def
    WHERE schemaname = public
    ORDER BY tablename;'
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

But I get error `ERROR:  anyelement is not a supported sql UDF return type`.

So, my question: "Is there any way to create `show_tables()` function in redhsift?"

Comment: you cannot do that kind of function in redshift

Comment: Try using a view, not a function

Comment: Interesting idea! I really should have asked about how to reduce typing when listing tables in redshift.

Answer (score 1):

If your return type is `anyelement`, atleast one of your input parameters **must** be `anyelement`.

For reference, visit the relevant section (towards the bottom of the page) at [Amazon Redshift Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-creating-a-scalar-udf.html)

Answer (score 0):

The Create Function comes with a `$$` notation (Dollar Notation). Please check the AWS Documentation.

For this I Hope the following helps :

```
CREATE FUNCTION show_tables(Some arguments here if required)
RETURNS ANYELEMENT VOLATILE 
AS $_$ SELECT DISTINCT tablename
    FROM pg_table_def
    WHERE schemaname = public
    ORDER BY tablename
    $_$
LANGUAGE sql;
```